# How to export a PNG sprite sheet from PNG sequence

Tags: animation, sprite, adobe-animate, image-sprite

I need a tool (software) which generates PNG sprite, vertical or horizontally. So I thought of Adobe animate, unless there's another easy application or plugin anyone can recommend.

So I have made an animation in After effects, and exported the PNG sequence, and imported it into Adobe animate. All the sequence gets places into the stage. So can any good Samaritan do a small tutorial showing what's the next steps from here to make a PNG vertical sprite sheet?

Thank you.

[image]

PS: I also noticed some quality loss when I imported the PNG sequence in Animate. is this automatically done for quality compression?

Example of PNG sprite sheet (vertical direction).

[image]

Comment: Imagemagick, dont worry if you have adobe suite installed then you actually have imagemagic installed too.